# Click event not updating in React/D3 when data is updated

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, mouseevent

I have a React component that renders a D3 bar chart where the bars are clickable. It works as expected until the parent state is updated. The bars update correctly but the click events on the bars are still bound to the previous data. I'm not sure if this is something I'm doing wrong in React or D3 or both. Any help is appreciated.

```
const DATA1 = [{"value":1}, {"value":1}]

const DATA2 = [{"value":3}, {"value":3}, {"value":3}, {"value":2}, {"value":2}]

const CLICK = 'chartClick'

function handleClick(data, i, els) {
  const element = els[i]

  const event = new Event(CLICK, {bubbles: true, detail: data})

  return element.dispatchEvent(event)
}

class D3Chart {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.svg = d3.select(selector).append('svg')
  }

  draw(data) {
    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data.map(i => i.value))])
      .range([0, 500])

    const barGroups = this.svg.selectAll('.barGroup').data(data)

    const barGroupsEnter = barGroups.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'barGroup')
      .attr('transform', (d, i) => {
        const y = (i * 25)

        return `translate(0, ${y})`
      })

    barGroupsEnter.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bar')
      .attr('height', 20)
      .attr('width', d => xScale(d.value))
      .on('click', handleClick)

    barGroups.exit().remove()
  }
}


class Chart extends React.Component {
  chartRef = React.createRef()

  componentDidMount() {
    const {data, onClick} = this.props

    this.chartRef.current.addEventListener(CLICK, onClick)

    this.chart = new D3Chart(this.chartRef.current)

    this.chart.draw(data)
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    const {data} = this.props

    return !_.isEqual(data, nextProps.data)
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const {data} = this.props

    this.chart.draw(data)
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.chartRef}></div>
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {data: DATA1}

  handleButtonClick = () => this.setState({data: DATA2})

  handleChartClick = (data, event) => console.log('data length on click', data.length)

  render() {
    const {data} = this.state

    console.log('data length on render', data.length)

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Update Data</button>
        <Chart data={data} onClick={(event) => this.handleChartClick(data, event)} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.root'))
```

The output on the initial render/click is:

```
"data length on render" 2
"data length on click" 2
```

The output after the data has been updated is:

```
"data length on render" 5
"data length on click" 2
```

I'm expecting the latter to be:

```
"data length on render" 5
"data length on click" 5
```

Codepen example here: https://codepen.io/bohmanart/pen/QPQJdX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below solution, change the onclick event inside chart to `this.chartRef.current.addEventListener(CLICK,   ()=>onClick(this.props.data.length);)`, the change the onClick props on chart to `onClick={this.handleChartClick}` and then change the handle chart click to `handleChartClick = (data) =>{ console.log('data length on click', data);}`

I am not sure of the use case on why you want to the pass the data from Chart component via `handleChartClick`  when it is already available in App class state. You can just use `this.state.data.length` in `handleChartClick`

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I tried what you suggested but I still receive the same results. New code pen: https://codepen.io/bohmanart/pen/wZmvGQ

Comment: Can you put ```() => onClick(this.props.data)``` instead if just data in add event listener of chart. Since add event listener is in componentDidMount and you have destructed data for the very first time, that data value will be referred for the subsequent  onClick calls. So you need to refer this.props.data to get the latest value.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense now that you point it out. I updated the codepen and that worked! My attempts at figuring this out for weeks have been futile. Thanks!

Comment: I found it important to add the event listeners on the update selection in addition to the the enter selection, otherwise the mouse event callback handler didn't have the latest version of the data, even if the render function that it's defined in does.